# Visual Studio. Notificar cuando una propiedad de un objeto esta siendo modificado

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Me gustaria saber si existe alguna opción de configuracion o algo para que hacer debug en un objeto cuando esta siendo modificado, no me refiero a un objeto creado por el usuario ya que eso es facil encapsulando las propiedades, me refiero por ejemplo si el texto de un label se modifica durante la ejecucion del programa que se pare la ejecucion en la linea de codigo donde ocurre esto.
P.D: Se que posiblemente no se trata de un tema de codigo pero creo que si existe una respuesta positiva tambien puede ser interesante para otras personas, por eso lo pregunto aqui.

Comment: No te he entendido muy bien la pregunta, ¿dices cuando cambias el contenido de una label?

Comment: @ErlantzCalvo si, me refiero a cuando cambia una propiedad de un objeto, el que tu quieras, lo comento porque a veces es dificil hacer debug cuando tienes timers, backgroundworkers y demas, seria interesante saber en que momento y quien ha modificado un determinado objeto y que se pare ahi la ejecucion

Comment: Pero si pones un punto de inflexión justo cuando se se va a modificar, se va a detener siempre ahí en principio

Comment: @ErlantzCalvo Si, puedo poner puntos de interrupcion en todos los sitios donde se hacen cambios, pero en aplicaciones grandes eso es un engorro muy grande, gracias de todos modos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente, la opcion existe pero no para codigo *managed*. Existen algunas opciones que se pueden usar sin embargo, como por ejemplo puntos de interrupción condicionales (se puede configurar un punto de interrupción para que solo se dispare si una variable ha cambiado) o poner el punto de interrupción en el setter de la propiedad o en el caso de un control en el evento correspondiente (*TextChanged* en el caso de un `TextBox` o `Label`).

Comment: ahh, gracias, es una pena, creo que seria interesante que Microsoft añadiera esta opcion en un futuro ya que seria de mucha utilizad en ciertas circunstancias. Gracias.

Comment: Si la opción no está disponible probablemente microsoft tenga alguna muy buena razón. Ahora mismo no te se decir cual,pero debe tenerla ;)